# How to split a items inside a list, surrounded by brackets, seperated by ,

Tags: python

I have a string of plot ploints such as:

```
plots = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 4), ... (0.4, 0.8) etc
```

But I want to split them into respective x and y's:

```
x = (0, 0, 1, ... 0.4)
y = (1, 2, 4, ... 0.8)
```

I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: Welcome! So what have you tried yet?

Answer (score 2):

python provides you with the [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html) function

```
x, y = zip(*plots)
```

which would provide your exact need, the asterisk would unpack the list into tuples, than the zip function "zips" the tuples together, that is creates a tuple for each index of the tuples

Comment: I think the OP is asking about other direction- ```unzip``` if you will.

Comment: As i've said, the asterisk would unpack the list into tuples, than the `zip()` function would zip the tuples together, which is what he wanted

Comment: *"that is creates a list for each index of the tuples"* - Not quite; they'll be tuples, not lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
plots = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 4), (0.4, 0.8)]

x = [plot[0] for plot in plots]
y = [plot[1] for plot in plots]
```

Comment: Should I say that your `x` and `y` are lists while in question they're tuples?

Answer (score 0):

This could be an inline solution

```py
plots = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 4)]
x, y = [item[0] for item in plots], [item[1] for item in plots]
```